# Get the last element of a row, separated with ;

Tags: text-processing

I have a file (test.txt), where the separator is ;. How can I write out the last element from each row? (the length of each element is different)

Answer (score 4):

```
sed 's/.*;//' < test.txt
```

Deletes everything up to the last `;` on each line.

Or with `awk`:

```
awk -F';' '{print $NF}' < test.txt
```

If you know in advance the number of fields, you can use `cut`. For instance, if there are 4 fields:

```
cut -d';' -f4 < test.txt
```

Beware though that if there are fewer than 4 fields on a line, then it will return an empty line *except* if there's only one field (no `;` in the line), in which case it will output the full line (that first field). A known misfeature in `cut`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line;
 do
 echo $(echo $line | awk -F ';' '{print $NF}')
done < test.txt
```

This is a simple script this will take each line of `test.txt` as input and will the print the last element separated by `;`.

Comment: Starting a new `awk` for every line seems a bit wasteful.

Comment: You may want to read [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716), [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346), [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123), [Why is printf better than echo?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803)

Comment: Thanks actually I am beginner to shell script.

Answer (score 0):

Or in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line ; do
    echo ${a##*;}
done
```